# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, mysql

i fetch MySql result using PHP array using this Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . LOCATION . ' ORDER BY category ';
$r = $db->query ( $sql ) or error ('Critical Error', mysql_error () );

while ($ROW = $db->fetcharray($r))
{
     if ($ROW[1] == '') //line 15
          $ROW[1] = $ROW['subcategory'];
}
```

fetcharray function:

```
function fetcharray ($query_id)

    {
        if(!$query_id)
        {
            $query_id = $this->query_res;
        }

        if($query_id)
    {
        $id = (int) $query_id;

        $this->q_array[$id] = @mysql_fetch_array($query_id,MYSQL_ASSOC); // LINE 124
        return $this->q_array[$id]; 
    }

        else

        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I see this error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\state.php on line 15
```

I change  `if ($ROW[1] == '') to if (isset($ROW[1]))` but I see again error.

`NOTE: i remove **MYSQL_ASSOC** from fetcharray function and fix error. i think my problem with fetcharray function how to fix this?`

How I can Fix this error?

Comment: Does this return a single row?



Try $ROW[0] if it does

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of $ROW to see what's contained there?

Comment: @shanehoban: with `$ROW[0]` i see same error `offset: 0`

Comment: Give us an output of `var_dump($ROW)`. Why do you use capital letters for ordinary variable, i.e. $ROW instead of $row?

Comment: @user3142680 OK why not do a foreach($db->fetcharray($r) as $ROW){ echo $ROW[0]} ... also +1 for [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Try doing `print_r($ROW)` within your `while`

Comment: It looks like You wrapped mysql_* function into class of Your own. I'm just guessing here but I think `fetcharray` returns empty array thats why You get this error. Use PDO instead.

Comment: i add fetcharray function to my Q

Comment: @rzymek: i see this error : `Notice: Undefined variable: ROW in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\state.php on line 17
NULL`

Comment: Did you put `var_dump` inside while loop?

Comment: @rzymek: array(3) { ["catsubsel"]=> string(1) "1" ["category"]=> string(27) "EML" [1]=> string(27) "EML" }

Comment: It's strange. 1. You have only one record in that table? 2. `$ROW`  actually contains index 1. I have no idea.

Comment: please see new edit Q.

Comment: Line 124 @ sigb suppress errors, remove it and retest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly answer to your question BUT you implemented some kind of wrapper for old and deprecated functions.

You should use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

In addition, you have inconsistent coding style. Once you use small letters for variables, another time you use capital letters.

Instead of this:

```
if ($ROW[1] == '') //line 15
          $ROW[1] = $ROW['subcategory'];
```

you should use:

```
if (!isset($ROW[1])) //line 15
          $ROW[1] = $ROW['subcategory'];
```

or this:

```
if (empty($ROW[1])) //line 15
          $ROW[1] = $ROW['subcategory'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if ($ROW[1] == '') //line 15
          $ROW[1] = $ROW['subcategory'];
```

You are directly accessing `$ROW[1]` ( and `$ROW[0]` as mentioned in comments) without even setting it. That is the reason it fails. If the name of the column in your database is "1" or "0" after all, try using `$ROW["1"] or $ROW["0"]`

Comment: It didn't explain why also `if (isset($ROW[1]))` gives that error. It indicates that $ROW isn't array at all.

Comment: Probably the fetcharray doesn't return an array at all